# How can I pass dynamic parameters to powershell script and iterate over the list?

Tags: powershell

I want to create a powershell script that accepts dynamic parameters and I also want to iterate through them.

eg:
I call the powershell script in the following manner.

```
ParametersTest.ps1 -param1 value1 -param2 value2 -param3 value3
```

And I should be able to access my params inside the script as follows:

```
for($key in DynamicParams) {
    $paramValue = DynamicParams[$key];
}
```

Is there anyway to do this in powershell? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built-in like that (essentially you're asking for PowerShell parameter parsing in the absence of *any* definition of those parameters). You can emulate it, though. With `$args` you can get at all arguments of the function as an array. You can then iterate that and decompose it into names and values:

```
$DynamicParams = @{}
switch -Regex ($args) {
  '^-' {
    # Parameter name
    if ($name) {
      $DynamicParams[$name] = $value
      $name = $value = $null
    }
    $name = $_ -replace '^-'
  }
  '^[^-]' {
    # Value
    $value = $_
  }
}
if ($name) {
  $DynamicParams[$name] = $value
  $name = $value = $null
}
```

To iterate over dynamic parameters you can either do something like you wrote

```
foreach ($key in $DynamicParams.Keys) {
  $value = $DynamicParams[$key]
}
```

(note the `foreach`, not `for`, the latter of which cannot work like you wrote it) or just iterate normally over the hash table:

```
$DynamicParams.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  $name = $_.Key
  $value = $_.Value
}
```